# How to set placeholder text for collection field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I want the placeholder field to say "Click to select" but the default placeholder still shows "Select Some Options"

```
 <%= f.input :tag_ids, as: :select, collection: Tag.order(:name), label_method: :name, input_html: {multiple: true}, label: "Select Category:", placeholder: "Click to select", required: true %>
```

Comment: You can make something similar to this <%= f.select(:status, [["Select One", ""],'Single','Married, Primary Applicant','Married, Second Applicant'], {}) %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `prompt` option, check simple-form's doc example

```
f.input :age, collection: 18..60, prompt: "Select your age", selected: 21
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections

You don't need to set `as: :select`, `select` is the default value when you render a collection.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for, you deserve more credit!

Answer (score 0):

Use select's include_blank option

```
select :object, :method, {:include_blank => ’-select-’}
```

See [the documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) for more info